# What is the difference between int* a = nullptr; and int *a = nullptr?

Tags: c++, pointers

Around blogs and forums I noticed that people uses different ways to declare pointers in c++:

```
int* a = nullptr;
```

and

```
int *a = nullptr;
```

There's a difference between the two methods? If yes, what is?

Comment: There's a third variant as well: `int*a=nullptr;`. And a fourth with `int * a = nullptr;`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In most contexts in C++ white space is ignored, this being one of them. You can write it like `int*a=nullptr;`, `int *a=nullptr;`, `int* a=nullptr;`, `int * a=nullptr;` or whatever else suits you, it all means the same thing to the compiler. Most of it in people's preference comes down to a style guide usually or other forms of justification for which is most readable within their own codebase.

As others have pointed out as well, this may relate more to a misunderstanding on how types are determined on declarations, which in many cases can indeed be confusing. I suggest you look into learning how to read those (things like the spiral rule are a good place to start even if it's not 100% accurate) since that will help alleviate much of the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

There's no difference.  And the `*` allways apply only to `a`.

Example:

```
int *a= nullptr, b=12;   // a is a pointer, b is a plain int
int* a= nullptr, b=12;   // still a is a pointer and b an int, 
                         // despite misleading impression conveyed
```